# make access to "/api/v1/login" without do any filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i want make access to `/api/v1/login` without do any filter

this the WebSecurityConfig  class

```
package com.siti.analyseapp.z_security.config.securityConfig;

import com.siti.analyseapp.z_security.config.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.siti.analyseapp.z_security.config.jwt.JwtRequestFilter;
import com.siti.analyseapp.z_utils.enums.UserRole;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private static final String SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE = "ROLE_" + UserRole.SUPER_ADMIN;
    private static final String ADMIN_ROLE = "ROLE_" + UserRole.ADMIN;
    private static final String CLIENT_ROLE = "ROLE_" + UserRole.CLIENT;

    @Autowired private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired @Qualifier("delegatedOncePerRequestFilter")
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Autowired private UserDetailsService jwtService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() {
        return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/login").permitAll()

                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"**/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE, ADMIN_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"**/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE, ADMIN_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"**/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"**/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE)

                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"**/laboratory/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"**/laboratory/**").hasAnyAuthority(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"**/laboratory/**").hasAnyAuthority(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"**/laboratory/**").hasAnyAuthority(SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE)

                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"**/client/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"**/client/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE, CLIENT_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"**/client/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"**/client/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)

                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"**/analyse/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"**/analyse/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"**/analyse/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"**/analyse/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_ROLE)

                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(jwtService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

and this the filter

```
package com.siti.analyseapp.z_security.config.jwt;

import com.siti.analyseapp.exceptions.ApiException;
import com.siti.analyseapp.z_security.service.JwtService;
import com.siti.analyseapp.z_utils.securityUtils.JwtUtil;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

import static com.siti.analyseapp.z_utils.securityUtils.JwtProperties.HEADER_STRING;
import static com.siti.analyseapp.z_utils.securityUtils.JwtProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX;

@Component("delegatedOncePerRequestFilter")
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired private JwtService jwtService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException, ApiException {

        final String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        String jwtToken = null;
        String username = null;
        if (header == null) {
//            System.out.println("Authorization header is missing");
            throw new ApiException("Authorization header is missing", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else if (!header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            throw new ApiException("Authorization header is not a bearer token", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else {
            jwtToken = header.substring(7);

            try {
                username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new ApiException("Unable to get Jwt", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                throw new ApiException("Jwt is expired", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = jwtService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            boolean isValid = jwtUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails);
            if (isValid) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

```
POST http://localhost:8036/api/v1/login
content-type: application/json

{
  "username": "admin.super@661",
  "password": "0000"
}
```

this the output

```
com.siti.analyseapp.exceptions.ApiException: Authorization header is missing
    at com.siti.analyseapp.z_security.config.jwt.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your Filter is always executing, even before the non authenticated calls.

To solve that you have to add the `shouldNotFilter` method to your filter:

```
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
      return request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/api/v1/login");
    }
```

Exactly the same issue has been discussed in the following video at 1:11:11 timestamp: [Spring Security, demystified by Daniel Garnier Moiroux](https://youtu.be/iJ2muJniikY?t=4271)